# Facing issue `read': No such file or directory @ > rb_sysopen in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, basic-authentication

Hello I have included given code in my 
config/app_config.yml

```
development:
  name: mytest
  password: secret
production:
  name: test
  password: Patest
```

config/application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/app_config.yml")[::Rails.env]
```

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
http_basic_authenticate_with :name => APP_CONFIG[:name], :password => APP_CONFIG[:password]
```

Now when I run rails server it gives me following error ::

> config/application.rb:8:in `read': No such file or directory @
>   rb_sysopen - /config/app_config.yml (Errno::ENOENT)   from
>   /Users/rails_app/config/application.rb:8:in`'

Please guide me what I am missing in my code how to solve this issue.

Comment: added `to_s` to Rails.root and checked?

Comment: no its not working @Sravan

Comment: try `Rails.root.join('config', 'app_config.yml')`

Comment: [please go through this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Paths/Root.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/app_config.yml")[::Rails.env]
```

inside your `Application` class.

```
module Something
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # something

    APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/app_config.yml")[::Rails.env]
  end
end
```